# How to convert Observable<Buffer> to InputStream?

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an `Observable` which emits `Buffer` items which contain byte arrays.

I would need to process this data via an InputStream. I'm aware that InputStreams are essentially blocking but I can use an Scheduler to work around this. My current issue is how to convert the formats.

```
Single<String> transform(Observable<Buffer> obs) {
  try (InputStream ins = ???) {
    String data = processData(ins);
    return Single.just(data);   
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)?

Comment: Yes, that would be an option. But I don't want to read the full buffer and use that in combination with the ByteArrayInputStream. I would like to "stream" from the obs to the InputStream without reading the whole obs upfront.

Comment: Write your own InputStream implementation, basically.  You're unlikely to find something pre-built to do this.  That doesn't mean it's impossible, just that you'll have to extend InputStream and implement its methods yourself.

Comment: Have a look at the [`PipedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) and `PipedInputStream`. You could feed the first from an IO thread and read blockingly from the second.

Comment: Ehhhhhhhh, that sounds like a bad idea.  Introducing threads here is not generally going to simplify your life.